# Convert git date using GNU date

Tags: git, bash, date, xargs

I would like to convert the git date into the format of Ymd. Here's my attempt:

```
$>>git log -1 --format="%cd" | xargs date Y%m%d
```

But this returns this error:

```
date: extra operand ‘Thu’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

Any ideas how to convert git date like this:

```
Thu Sep 19 17:03:12 2013 +0100
```

To something like this:

```
20130919
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It'd be easier if you make `git` emit the UNIX timestamp.  Say:

```
git log -1 --format="%at" | xargs -I{} date -d @{} +%Y%m%d
```

From the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> **`%at`**: author date, UNIX timestamp

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `%cd`, use `%ct` which would get the timestamp:

```
git log -1 --format="%ct" | xargs -i --  date -d '@{}' '+%Y%m%d'
```

Answer (score 2):

You want ... `| xargs -i date -d {} +%Y%m%d`.

Notice the `-d` option for passing in a date other than the current time (and `xargs -i` to get it in the middle of the command line) and the `+` to specify the date format specifier (and the missing `%` for `%Y`).

Equivalently, without `xargs`,

```
date -d "$(git log -1 --format="%cd")" +%Y%m%d
```